# meson `get_option()` to find `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/` directory

Tags: dbus, meson-build

Meson uses `get_option('bindir')` to find the binary directory, which should be `/usr/bin` in most cases.

I have configuration file for d-bus, the file should be like `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/<file>.conf`, how can I use the similar method to find the path of `etc/dbus-1/system.d/` in `meson.build` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way you would do this is with:

```
dbus_dir = get_option('sysconfdir') / 'dbus-1' / 'system.d'
dbus_file = dbus_dir / '<file>.conf'
```

`sysconfigdir` is the name of the directory that is usually `/etc`, and then you'd build the rest of the string yourself.

The [directory names are documented here](https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html#directories)